# How to update local files on all the postgres nodes

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication, master-slave, pg-hba.conf

I have a multi-node Postgres cluster running in High availability mode following the `primary-standby` architecture.

```
postgres-0                                               5/5     Running            0          111s
postgres-1                                               5/5     Running            0          3m4s
postgres-monitor-0                                       4/4     Running            0          13m
```

One of the pod is `primary` and the other pod is in `standby` mode which gets replicated from `primary` in a `synchronous` manner, while standby remains in the `read-only` mode.

I am running the following CRUD commands to update a local file:

```
-- Update pg_config to allow access to the users
create table hba ( lines text );
copy hba from '/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf';

insert into hba (lines) values ('host     all              all       0.0.0.0/0    md5');
insert into hba (lines) values ('host     all              all       ::/0         md5');

copy hba to '/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf';

-- reload the config
select pg_reload_conf();
```

The issue is, the file `/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` is getting updated on the `primary` node and not on the `standby` node (as all queries go to master), this means when the `primary` node goes down and `standby` becomes a new `primary` the config changes will be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `copy` command can be executed on all the Postgres nodes:

```
psql -U postgres -h postgres-0.postgres-agent.default -c "copy hba to '/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf'"
psql -U postgres -h postgres-1.postgres-agent.default -c "copy hba to '/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf'"
```

The `copy` command can be executed on the `standby` node even though it's in `ready-only` mode.

---

Below are the complete sequence of steps *after* verifying all the nodes have joined the cluster and replication have started:

Step 1: (Execute on Primary node, this will get replicated to all the standby nodes)

```
-- Update pg_config to allow access to the users
create table hba ( lines text );
copy hba from '/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf';

insert into hba (lines)
    select 'host     <database>              all       0.0.0.0/0    scram-sha-256'
        where not exists (
            select 1 from hba where lines = 'host     <database>              all       0.0.0.0/0    scram-sha-256'
            );

insert into hba (lines)
    select 'host     <database>              all       ::/0         scram-sha-256'
        where not exists (
            select 1 from hba where lines = 'host     <database>              all       ::/0         scram-sha-256'
            );
```

Step 2: (Depends on the number of replicas)

```
psql -U postgres -h postgres-0.postgres-agent.default -c "copy hba to '/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf'"
psql -U postgres -h postgres-1.postgres-agent.default -c "copy hba to '/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf'"
```

Step 3:

```
-- reload the config
select pg_reload_conf();
```

Answer (score 0):

I must add that this approach does not look very secure to me.

You cannot use tables (even temporary ones) on a standby server.
I think the easiest way to approach this is to write a [PL/PerlU](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plperl.html) or [PL/PythonU](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) to do the necessary file modifications. You also have to call the function `pg_reload_comf()` to activate the modifications.

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz for the response. Are you suggesting to create a script and then run it in the standby server?

Comment: I should also mention, the standby nodes are in ready only. Also updated the question.

Comment: I agree the pg_hba.conf is making it un-secure, but the infrastructure is secured using istio mtls.

Comment: You could use a `DO` statement or a PL/pgSQL function.

Comment: I created this https://gist.github.com/vishrantgupta/57a2c50f1081d6793f7d87cdb326596e psql but it is not running on all the postgres nodes.

Comment: Of course not. I told you to use an array rather than a table.

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz for reviewing it. I am not sure if I followed you, could you please point me to an example of how I can change the `COPY` command to use `ARRAY`?

Comment: You cannot use `COPY` for that.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer! `PL/PerlU` or `PL/PythonU` will add a dependency on package `postgresql-plpython3`, and I will have to add another docker layer to install the dependencies on top of the existing postgres image, which I am avoiding.